# Prove that the sequence $x_n = 1 +\frac{ sin (n+ \pi) }{n} $ is a cauchy sequence

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Prove that the sequence $x_n = 1 +\frac{ sin (n+ \pi) }{n} $  is a cauchy sequence using the definition:

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N\in\mathbb{N}: n,m\ge N\implies |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon.$$

I have tried to prove: $ | \frac{ n-sin(n)}{n}  -  \frac{ m -sin(m)}{m} | \leq \epsilon$.
The triangle inequality did not work for me and I don't know how to prove it with the provided definition.

I could argue that the sequence converges to 1 and is therefore cauchy. However, I need to prove this with the definition.

Please help me.

Comment: $\frac {n-\sin(n)}{n} = 1 - \frac {\sin n}{n}$ With that simpification the problem gets easier.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you very much, it was a typo.

Comment: $$\sin(n+\pi) = \sin n \cos \pi + \sin \pi \cos n = -\sin n$$ so this is really $$x_n = 1 - \dfrac{\sin n}{n}$$ isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\frac{\sin (π+m)}{m}-\frac{\sin (π+n)}{n}|\le$

$|\frac{\sin (π+m)}{m}| +|\frac{\sin (π+n)}{n}|\le$

$1/m+1/n;$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $n_0 > 2/\epsilon$ (Archimedean principle).

For $m\ge n \ge n_0:$

$|\frac{\sin (π+m)}{m}-\frac{\sin (π+n)}{n}|\le 1/m+1/n \le 2/n \le 2/n_0 <\epsilon.$

Comment: Hello thank you very much. Could you please tell me why it's  $\leq 1/m + 1/n$? I'm learning on my own and I don't know how we got there. Thanks again.

Comment: smalllearner. Triangle inequality:$ |a +b| \le |a|+|b|$, now: $|\sin(pi +m)/m+\sin (pi+n)/n| \le |\sin(pi+m)/m|+|\sin (pi +n)/n| =|\sin (..)|/m+|\sin (..)|/n\le 1/m+1/n$ since $|\sin (pi+n)| \le 1$, same for m index.Ok, if not come again:)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much

Comment: smalllearner. Welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Note that\begin{align}|x_m-x_n|&=\left|1+\frac{\sin(m+\pi)}m-\left(1+\frac{\sin(n+\pi)}n\right)\right|\\&=\left|\frac{\sin(m+\pi)}m-\frac{\sin(n+\pi)}n\right|\\&\leqslant\frac1m+\frac1n.\end{align}So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1N<\frac\varepsilon2$ and then$$m,n\geqslant N\implies|x_m-x_n|\leqslant\frac1m+\frac1n\leqslant\frac2N<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Hello thank you very much. Could you please tell me why it's  $\leq 1/m + 1/n$? I'm learning on my own and I don't know how we got there. Thanks again.

Comment: \begin{align}|x_m-x_n|&=\left|\frac{\sin(m+\pi)}m-\sin{(n+\pi)}n\right|\\&\leqslant\left|\frac{\sin(m+\pi)}m\right|+\left|\frac{\sin(n+\pi)}n\right|\text{ (triangle inequality)}\\&\leqslant\frac1m+\frac1n\end{align}